# iPad Keyboard: mode based key augmentation

Tags: cocoa, xcode, ipad

When using the "add Account..." function in the 'Mail,Contacts, Calendars' section in 'Settings' on an iPad, selecting the address field causes the keyboard to change the labels of the <kbd>!</kbd>, and <kbd>?</kbd>. keys, shorten the right '.?123' and <kbd>space</kbd> key and add two new keys (<kbd>_</kbd> and <kbd>-</kbd>)

I have also seen the Keyboard augment to show a <kbd>.com</kbd> key for URLs.

Im guessing you can pass the keyboard a 'url mode' or 'email address mode' type argument, has anyone manipulated the keyboard in such a way before and what degree of plasticity is there for actual labels or modes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of defined [`UIKeyboardType`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/Reference/UITextInputTraits.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIKeyboardType)'s. You must use one of those.